# How can I get mean by a unique factor column?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this with more than 100 columns:

```
ID  regulation press treat
1001 test1        0.2  b
1001 test1        1    c
1002 test2        2    s
1002 test2        3    s
1004 test1        4    s
1004 test1        5    f
1005 test2        6    w
1006 test2        6    u
1006 test2        1    h
```

Each ID has only one regulation and only two possible regulations occur in the database (test1 and test2)

I basically want to **SUM** all the unique occurrences of ID

Intended output

```
test1: 2
test2: 3
```

Which means, test1 has occurred in 2 unique IDs and test2 has occurred in 3 unique IDs.

Comment: can you also show the expected output.  Is it similar to the regulation column?

Comment: The expected output remains the same as before. The new columns are not involved in the analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 rowSums(table(unique(df[, c("regulation", "ID")])))
 # test1 test2 
 #  2     3
```

Or

```
  table(unique(df[,c('regulation', 'ID')])[,"regulation"])
  #   test1 test2 
  #    2     3
```

Or  using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
count(unique(select(df, ID, regulation)), regulation)
#using the %>%, the above code would be
#df %>%
   #   select(ID, regulation)  
   #    unique() 
   #    count(regulation)

#  regulation n
#1      test1 2
#2      test2 3
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(ID = c(1001L, 1001L, 1002L, 1002L, 1004L, 1004L, 
 1005L, 1006L, 1006L), regulation = c("test1", "test1", "test2", 
 "test2", "test1", "test1", "test2", "test2", "test2"), press = c(0.2, 
 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 1), treat = c("b", "c", "s", "s", "s", "f", 
 "w", "u", "h")), .Names = c("ID", "regulation", "press", "treat"
 ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually the dataframe will have large number of columns, and I only gave the two I need. How can I use the row names instead of 2:1?

Comment: @maximusyoda please show an updated example in your post with multiple columns and the expected result.  Here `2:1` is just to rearrange the columns.

Comment: I have updated two more columns. But basically the dataframe has 100s of columns. So instead of referencing by 2:1, I would like to reference the name of the column itself.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Akrun's answer, which is excellent; you can do this easily using a `data.table` approach.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
rowSums(table(unique(dt[,ID, regulation])))
#test1 test2 
#2     3
```